# When installing a solution from 3rd-party, every step goes fine, except to activate its feature

Tags: installation

It is deployed successfully, but when activate it, come up with this error msg:
"Feature with Id '1170444c-cb9f-4409-9271-82f46a90b23a' is not installed in this farm, and cannot be added to this scope"

Plz, advise where I go wrong.

Comment: What are you using to deploy it? Are you running an EXE? Or are you using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the feature is not installed correctly or does not have full trust in the GAC.  I would remove and reinstall that feature by running the following stsadm commands:

```
1. stsadm.exe -o retractsolution -name xxxx.wsp -immediate 
2. stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs
3. stsadm.exe –o addsolution –filename xxxx.wsp
4. stsadm.exe –o deploysolution –name xxxx.wsp -allowgacdeployment -immediate
5. stsadm.exe -o execadmsvcjobs
```

Replace the xxxx.wsp with the name of the actual WSP package, which contains `'1170444c-cb9f-4409-9271-82f46a90b23a'` Feature .

Hope this helps.